# Removing and Replacing Flourescent Ballast

Tags: light-fixture, ballast

I went to flip the switch to turn on the overhead light in my kitchen recently, and there was a flash of light and it stopped working. I replaced the lamps, but it still won't turn on.

Here's a picture:
[image]

**So I want to replace it, but I can't figure out how it is fastened to the ceiling and how to get it down. Any ideas?**

Additionally, would it be possible for me to replace it myself? The big extenuating factor is that my house still uses old fashion fuses and the fuses are not labeled so I don't know how to turn off the electricity if there isn't just aplug where the old ballast connected.

Here's a picture of the fusebox:
[image]

Comment: One problem is your fuses are too big.  30 amps should only be for stove/range or dryer.  All others should be 15 or maybe if the wires are 12 gauge 20 amps.  To be sure pull the two mains on top, but if guessing the fuse with the black marks(bottom right) is the one, but it not my fingers touching power.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The center section of the fixture hides the ballast and the anchoring.

Squeeze it together at the tabs to release it along one side and it will come out.  Reinstallation is obviously, the opposite.

As for the fuses, you should have a noncontact voltage tester at the switch and unscrew the fuses one by one till you find the one that protects that circuit.

Comment: Tip: Assume that the manufacturer made the effort to provide sheet metal with edges sharper than razor blades. Wearing gloves when removing the center cover may reduce blood loss considerably. Aside: If the non-contact voltage tester shows no power then the flash of light probably coincided with a fuse blowing.

Answer (score 1):

No big deal on having real fuses! I would recommend just removing the ballast completely and going with LED tubes, a bit of re-wiring is needed and a label applied saying that the tubes are now 120 V and don't need a ballast. They'll be more efficient than the tubes that require  a ballast.

Comment: Having 30 amp fuses on household circuits might be a big deal.

Comment: @crip659  agreed. but since the OP didn't ask about the fuse sizes, I felt it was OT to mention it, I've gotten snipped here before about saying "hey, what about this", so I'm being extra cautious.